# Packaging up ASPX, CSS and image files

Tags: asp.net

I'm designing a simple framework for small websites to be used in an intranet. The websites will all be similar, but there will be a few pages, or controls on pages, that are different. I would like to be able to version and maintain the common framework part of the websites as if they were a regular library - if I need to update CSS then I only have to do it in one place. Can I package-up ASPX files, images and CSS and distribute them like this? What am I missing?

My goal is to allow the developers of the few core content pages to get up and running with the websites quickly, with standard styles and images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can embed CSS and images into a DLL, and extract the paths for these files from the DLL.  This is what AJAX server control libraries have been doing: marking a CSS file as an embedded resource, adding a WebResource(".filename.css", "text/css"), and using Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(..) which specified the object in the DLL to extract.

HTH.